Are messages a reliable way to send large amounts of data into and out of a web app in a React Native webview?
I am researching the viability of loading my existing web app in my React Native app while it is offline.  Based on some older SO questions, it does seem possible. However, I also need know if its possible to do the three following things:

Dynamically load roughly 2 MB of JSON data into the web app in the webview.
Access Camera, file system, and geolocation in the web app.
Send roughly 2 MB of JSON data and multiple photos back to the React Native app to be saved locally.

I know that iframes and the web view can send messages but as I understand it, that's generally used for sending URLs or other flags.
In short, the primary question is are messages a reliable way to send large amounts of data into and out of a web app in the webview (iframe) of React Native?

I focused the question more to be able what is possible with messages.

My experience of using the postMessage API, is between webpages, rather than an App. I have always found it to be reliable, but if something does go wrong then you don’t get any feedback. So if the data is important, you’ll need to build your own ACK layer on top of it.

Good point. The ACK layer is an important consideration. So you haven't had trouble with several megabytes of data either?

My use case is normally a rapid stream of small  data, but as long as the data is serialisable I have never had an issue with any sized message.

The only issue I ever have, is that if you send a message before an iframe has loaded, it throws an error to the browser console, that is not returned to JS, so it is thus undetectable to the code, but users of my library see it and get upset, even though the code just resends the message if it doesn’t get the ACK.

Just had another thought, you would have to convert the images to binary encoded strings, as you cannot send pointers by postMessage. The biggest issue I think you will face is performance, as all the data will have to be encoded, copied across and then decoded.

That's a good point to keep in mind. Thank you.
